# Compile error: User-defined type not defined using PowerPoint VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

```vb
Sub SELLSHEETUPDATES_Macro()

Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim onlyFileName As String, folderPath As String, pptFiles As String, removeFileExt As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

folderPath = Range("C5").Text & ""
pptFiles = Dir(folderPath & "*.pp*")

If pptFiles = "" Then
MsgBox "No files found"
Exit Sub
End If

Do While pptFiles \<\> ""

Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue

On Error Resume Next
Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(folderPath & pptFiles)

On Error GoTo 0
removeFileExt = InStr(1, oPPTFile.Name, ".") - 1
onlyFileName = Left(oPPTFile.Name, removeFileExt)

On Error Resume Next

oPPTFile.ExportAsFixedFormat oPPTFile.Path & "" & onlyFileName & ".pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint
oPPTFile.Close

pptFiles = Dir()
Loop

oPPTApp.Quit

Set oPPTFile = Nothing
Set oPPTApp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox " Successfully converted"
End Sub
Sub SELLSHEETUPDATES()

End Sub
```

It highlights

```
Sub SELLSHEETUPDATES_Macro()
```

I googled this code to save all of the PowerPoint presentations in one folder as separate PDF files. This is to reduce time opening each PowerPoint file and saving a copy as a PDF file.

Comment: In your Excel file you need to add a VB project reference to the Powerpoint object library.

Answer (score 0):

ppFixedFormatTypePDF and ppFixedFormatIntentPrint are both PowerPoint defined constants; Excel doesn't know what they are, hence the error message.

Either use 2 for both of them or define them both as constants (as Long = 2) at the top of your module.

```
Do While pptFiles \<\> ""
```

should be

```
Do While pptFiles <> ""
```

or better,

```
Do While Len(pptFiles) = 0
```

Also, you're creating the PPT application object each time through the loop but not releasing it until you've escaped from the loop. Create the object BEFORE the beginning of your loop.

And finally, your code sorta smells like the stuff ChatGPT arfs out. It seems to want to do everything in Excel, even when you're asking for stuff that'd be simpler to do within PPT. Other than having the folder name in a cell in Excel, is there some particular value to doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunPowerPointToPDF()
    ' Call the PowerPoint to PDF conversion macro
    ConvertPowerPointToPDF
End Sub

Sub ConvertPowerPointToPDF()
    Dim objPPT As Object
    Dim objPresentation As Object
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFile As String
    
    ' Set the folder path
    strFolder = "C:location"
    
    ' Create PowerPoint application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If objPPT Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint is not available. Please make sure PowerPoint is installed.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    objPPT.Visible = msoTrue ' Show PowerPoint application
    
    ' Loop through all PowerPoint files in the folder
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.ppt*")
Do While strFile <> ""
    ' Open PowerPoint presentation
    Set objPresentation = objPPT.Presentations.Open(strFolder & strFile)
    
    If Not objPresentation Is Nothing Then
        ' Save as PDF
        objPresentation.SaveAs strFolder & Replace(strFile, ".ppt", ".pdf"), 32 ' 32 corresponds to ppSaveAsPDF
        
        ' Close the presentation
        objPresentation.Close
    End If
    
    ' Get the next file
    strFile = Dir
Loop

    
    ' Quit PowerPoint application
    objPPT.Quit
    Set objPPT = Nothing
End Sub
```